# (PHP) var_dumping an object in structured format.

Tags: php, object, var-dump

I need to analyze an object in my code, but when I do a var_dump (or print_r) it just prints the object out with no structure, for example:

```
[0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#2185 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(1) ["tag"]=> string(3) "div" ["attr"]=> array(1) { ["class"]=> string(36) "element element--collection internal" } ["children"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#2187 (
```

I need to see it in a more structured format so I can see what is going on, i.e.:

```
object(simple_html_dom_node)#2185 (9) { 
    ["nodetype"]=> int(1) 
    ["tag"]=> string(3) "div" 
    ["attr"]=> array(1) 
    { 
        ["class"]=> string(36) "element element--collection internal" 
    } 
    ["children"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#2187 (9)
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: var_dump within <pre> </pre> tags should help

Comment: `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($object); echo "</pre>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you want is actually how `var_dump()` prints the object. The problem is that you're doing it in an HTML document, and the browser reformats it.

If you put it inside a `<pre>` tag, the browser will leave the formatting alone. So:

```
echo "<pre>"; var_dump($object); echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `var_export()`, this function will give you a more readable structure of the object or data.

Comment: The browser will still reformat it so it won't be easy to read. The difference is that `var_export()` can be pasted into code to recreate the data.

Comment: @Barmar using `var_export()` with the `<pre>` can help him to solve the issue.

Comment: That's true. Although the output from `var_export()` is not actually as useful for debugging. It doesn't have the lengths of arrays and strings, for instance.